# Stop specific function execution in jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, background

I've got the following code which changes the background of a page with jQuery. I've got buttons for next, previous, and play/pause. It works really well like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imageSet = ["1.JPG", "2.JPG", "3.JPG", "4.JPG", "5.JPG", "6.JPG"];
var currentImageSet = 0;

function changeBackgroundImages() {
    img2Fade();
    setTimeout(img1Fade, 5000);
}

function img1Fade(){
    $('#back-img1').css({background: 'url(./img/bgimgs/small/' + imageSet[++currentImageSet] + ')'});
    $('#back-img1').ready( function() { 
        $('#back-img1').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#back-img2').fadeOut('slow');
        if (currentImageSet >= imageSet.length - 1) {
                currentImageSet -= imageSet.length;
            };
    });
}

function img2Fade(){
    $('#back-img2').css({background: 'url(./img/bgimgs/small/' + imageSet[++currentImageSet] + ')'});
    $('#back-img2').ready( function() { 
        $('#back-img2').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#back-img1').fadeOut('slow');
        if (currentImageSet >= imageSet.length - 1) {
                currentImageSet -= imageSet.length;
            };
    });
};

function PlaySlide () {
    setInterval(changeBackgroundImages, 10000);
};

function NavigateSlide () {
    $('#prev-arrow').click(function() {
        var back1display = $( '#back-img1' ).css( "display" );
        var back2display = $( '#back-img2' ).css( "display" );
        if(back1display == 'block'){
                if (currentImageSet <= 0) {
                        currentImageSet = imageSet.length-1;
                    };
            $('#back-img2').css({background: 'url(./img/bgimgs/small/' + imageSet[--currentImageSet] + ')'});
            $('#back-img2').ready( function() { 
                $('#back-img2').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#back-img1').fadeOut('slow');
            });
        } else if (back2display == 'block'){
                if (currentImageSet <= 0) {
                        currentImageSet = imageSet.length-1;
                    };
            $('#back-img1').css({background: 'url(./img/bgimgs/small/' + imageSet[--currentImageSet] + ')'});
            $('#back-img1').ready( function() { 
                $('#back-img1').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#back-img2').fadeOut('slow');
            });
        };
    });
    $( '#next-arrow' ).click(function() {
        var back1display = $( '#back-img1' ).css( "display" );
        var back2display = $( '#back-img2' ).css( "display" );
        if(back1display == 'block'){
            img2Fade();
        } else if (back2display == 'block'){
            img1Fade();
        };
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    var paused = 0;

    if(paused == 0) {
        PlaySlide ();
    } else if (paused == 1) {
        NavigateSlide ();
    };
});
</script>
```

That is if I write in the code the value of "paused" to 0 or 1.
My problems start when I try to change the value of "paused" with the click event on the Play/Pause button. For that I have the following code in the document ready function:

```
$('#play-btn').click(function(){ 
        paused = pause();
        if(paused == "0") {
            $('#jQuery_log').html( "Slideshow playing | pause = " + paused )
            PlaySlide ();
        } else if(paused == "1")  {
            $('#jQuery_log').html( "Slideshow paused | pause = " + paused )
            NavigateSlide ();
        };
    });
```

And the `pause ()` function:

```
function pause() { 
          if (paused == 0) {
              $('#gal-play').css({background: 'url(./img/other_resources/gal_play.png)'});
              return 1;
          } else if (paused == 1) {
              $('#gal-play').css({background: 'url(./img/other_resources/gal_pause.png)'});
              return 0;
          };
    };
```

This works too, until somepoint. It changes the values of "paused" but it doesn't stop the execution of `PlaySlide ()` or `NavigateSlide ()` functions after clicking the button.

Can anyone suggest a good approach on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop your interval to pause it:

```
var play;
function PlaySlide () {
    play = setInterval(changeBackgroundImages, 10000);
};
function StopSlide () {
    clearInterval(play);
};
```